# JPA: mapping a View as Entity with a dummy ID

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to map a Database **View** into an JPA **Entity**. As the Entities needs an ID, I look for a solution in StackOverflow and I found that the best approach is to set **all the columns as ID**.

All seems to work fine, unless one of the columns has a **null value**. When it occurs, JPA returns a null object.

Does anybody had the same problem? Is there any way to specify a dummy ID column that really doesn't exist in the View?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to place the identity logic inside the view itself.

One solution would be to use database functions like `ROW_NUMBER` or `ROWID` to accomplish this as part of the view's query.  There are others of course, but doing this as part of the view's query makes the most logical sense.

I would however recommend you mark such entity as `@Immutable` since the data is being fetched from a view which is read-only.  This simply prevents problems or mistakes from occurring in code where you may *attempt* to modify such an entity and it isn't permissible.

Comment: I thought with this solution too, but I hope to find a best "programmatical" solution that doesn't require to modify the view, thanks ;)

Comment: Good luck, but aside from using an `@IdClass` or `@EmbeddedId` to represent a composite of columns which are guaranteed not-null and unique, I'm not aware of any other option.